# How to make pdf reader same as this image

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular11, pdf-viewer

I read some package documentations, but there is noone  at this  style.
I read

1. `ng2-pdf-viewer`
2. `@syncfusion/ej2-angular-pdfviewer`
3. `ngx-extended-pdf-viewer`

Can someone  help me and  tell  the  package?
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qq7j.png)

Comment: So you want one like chrome? Afaik many of these pdf viewer packages are ports from the firefox one cause the firefox ui is also based on js. If you don't need the added functionality of one you can control may just embed them the default way with the browser. Otherwise you could playaround with the css and customize it like you want or maybe you have luck someone else did it already in a fork

Comment: I can also  add functionality, but  I have no idea ho can I do this with all functionallity (download, print, etc...)